# Property Sheets in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I'm using VS2005 and I have a property sheet (vsprops file) that I'm adding to all the C++ projects but I can't seem to find out how to add them to the C# projects. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/HadiPropertySheet.aspx

Comment: No I'm talking about property sheets as in vsprops files. Also, I meant 'projects' in my question not 'solutions.'

Answer (score 8):

Although there is no exact equivalent of property sheets in C#, there is at least one easy way to accomplish what you want: csproj files can import other project files, so you can have a common project file that only defines the output path.

It's all been covered already: [How to set the output path of several visual C# projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621461/how-to-set-the-output-path-of-several-visual-c-sharp-projects).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but still... Just edit the project file manually and add an `<import>` section to use a property sheet:

```
<Project ...>
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\Local.props" />
</Project>
```

No need to have a real project file to import.

Comment: But remember, putting a property in local.props, means you should also remove it from the file that includes it. The last property wins...

Answer (score 2):

A project property sheet is an implementation detail of the C++ IDE.  There is no equivalent for the C# IDE.  Mostly because there are so few knobs to tweak.  As compared with the C and C++ compiler and linker who have, what, over 100 options.  The managed code way is to use [attributes] instead.

Project + Properties to change the C# settings.  Rejoice in the sparsity.  Actually changing any of them is quite rare, the project template takes care of them, if necessary.

Comment: Boy is this wishful thinking.

Comment: IMHO it is not C++ vs C#, its about how much control you want over your solution. Recently I got SLN with about 90+ C# projects with a real mess of how project template looked like at the time of creation and how many hand made changes were done there. I need to change a single prop - DebugType for all of them. I plan to do it by creating a few props files and include it in all of csprojs. Starting from this point in time on I will have full control over setting DebugType in a clean way.

Comment: It would be better if Visual Studio allows setting a single prop for multiple selection of projects. But... you know... someone probably decided that it is too costly to implement such in Visual Studio.